# Appcenter wont build iOS after implementing custom base class from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, base-class, visual-studio-app-center

I made a BaseTrackingViewController for a couple VC's that need tracking.
Code was built with the latest xcode-beta and development versions. Run on a simulator iOS 14.5 and on a real iPhone 11 Pro with iOS 15.0 public beta. Run's perfectly.

Untill compilation in appcenter
Following error

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ios' from project 'ios')
    cd /Users/runner/work/1/s
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name ios -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Xfrontend -enable-swift3-objc-inference -Xfrontend -warn-swift3-objc-inference-minimal @/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios.SwiftFileList -DRELEASE -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -swift-version 5 -I /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LGSideMenuController -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MaterialShowcase -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Mixpanel-swift -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwifCron -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftClient -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftCron -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwipeCellKit -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/TrustKit -F /Users/runner/work/1/s/Pods/AppCenter/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/iOS -c -num-threads 3 -output-file-map /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-numerics/Sources/_NumericsShims/include -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LGSideMenuController/LGSideMenuController.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MaterialShowcase/MaterialShowcase.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Mixpanel-swift/Mixpanel.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift/Reachability.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwifCron/SwifCron.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftClient/SwiftClient.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftCron/SwiftCron.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/TrustKit/TrustKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios-Swift.h -working-directory /Users/runner/work/1/s
CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'ios' from project 'ios')
    cd /Users/runner/work/1/s
    /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/sources-dfeeee -supplementary-output-file-map /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/supplementaryOutputs-d07bd5 -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -I /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LGSideMenuController -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MaterialShowcase -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Mixpanel-swift -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwifCron -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftClient -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftCron -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwipeCellKit -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/TrustKit -F /Users/runner/work/1/s/Pods/AppCenter/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/iOS -g -module-cache-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -O -D RELEASE -D COCOAPODS -enable-swift3-objc-inference -warn-swift3-objc-inference-minimal -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/runner/work/1/s -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/ios-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-numerics/Sources/_NumericsShims/include -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LGSideMenuController/LGSideMenuController.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MaterialShowcase/MaterialShowcase.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Mixpanel-swift/Mixpanel.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift/Reachability.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwifCron/SwifCron.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftClient/SwiftClient.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftCron/SwiftCron.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/TrustKit/TrustKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-efllujispuaysmafvdethlpdlhcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ios.build/Release-iphoneos/ios.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -target-sdk-version 14.4 -module-name ios -num-threads 3 -output-filelist /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/outputs-831b78
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal armv7
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
(3 failures)

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

Here is the base UIViewController class

```
class BaseTrackingViewController: UIViewController {
    var screenName: String { return String.empty }
    lazy private var trackingProperties: [String: MixpanelType] = ["SCREEN_NAME": screenName]
    var customTrackingProperties: [String: MixpanelType]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let properties = customTrackingProperties != nil ? mergeDictionaries(trackingProperties, customTrackingProperties!) : trackingProperties
        trackEvent(event: "LOADED", properties: properties)
    }
    
    func viewDidUnload() {
        trackEvent(event: "DISMISSED", properties: trackingProperties)
    }
    
    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        viewDidUnload()
    }
    
    func trackEvent(_ event: String, properties: [String: MixpanelType]) {
        let properties = mergeDictionaries(trackingProperties, properties)
        trackEvent(event: event, properties: properties)
    }
    
    private func trackEvent(event: String, properties: [String: MixpanelType]) {
        Mixpanel.mainInstance().track(event: event, properties: properties)
    }
    
    private func mergeDictionaries(_ dict1: [String: MixpanelType], _ dict2: [String: MixpanelType]) -> [String: MixpanelType] {
        return dict1.merging(dict2){(_, second) in second}
    }
}
```

The way the base class is implemented is like so:

```
class RandomViewController: BaseTrackingViewController, DeltaChangedDelegate {
    
    override var screenName: String  { return "PersonalSummary" }
    var delta = 0
    var deltaDelegate: DeltaChangedDelegate?
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        deltaDelegate = self
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // to track something extra when initialized
        customTrackingProperties = ["DELTA": delta]
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func doSomething() {
        trackEvent("SomeEvent", properties: ["SomeProperty": "SomeValue"])
    }
    func onReceiveDeltaChanged() {
        trackEvent("LOADED", properties: ["DELTA": delta])
    }
}
protocol DeltaChangedDelegate: AnyObject {
    func onDeltaChanged()
}
```

Created a work around to know when the viewcontroller was "dismissed" by the user. Since doing dismiss on the view controller itself resulted in the navigation stack beeing cleared. Which in my case is not desired.

```
class RandomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        if let vc = super.popViewController(animated: animated) as? BaseTrackingViewController {
            vc.viewDidUnload()
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

When removing all of this code and its implementations, appcenter builds again.
There are no compiler errors in the xcode-beta, and live xcode apps.
Havent got any changes to project or target settings or packages

Answer (score 0):

Found the fault

the declartion of

```
func viewDidUnload() { 
    ....
}
```

conflicted with the old declartion of viewDidUnload (which is deprecated and removed since iOS 7.0) with the appcenter compiler. renaming it fixed the problem